# OP Amp-Difference amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I have a question about an exercise considering op amps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWBSFI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The task is to give an expression for V_OUT as a function of V_IN, V0, R1 and R2.

Could anyone explain me how to solve such a task? Because I've always had struggles with op amps.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

I tried to solve this task using superposition. My result was:

\$V_{OUT}=V_0-V_{IN}*\frac{2*R_2+R_1}{2R_1+R_2}\$

Is this correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework with no attempt at a solution

Comment: Well I tried superposition now which gave me the result: V_OUT=V0-V_IN*((2*R2+R1)/(2R1+R2)).

Comment: Could you tell me if that's right?

Comment: Doesn't look correct to me, you have made a mistake gain of Vin to Vout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that it's an ideal OP-amp (voltage at (+)input = voltage at (-)input)

So, voltage dividing gives:

\$_{(+)}input=V_0\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$

```
And for (-)input: current from left = current from right
```

\$\frac{V_{IN}-_{(-)}input}{R_1}= \frac{_{(-)}input-V_{OUT}}{R_2}\$

\$\frac{R_2(V_{IN}-_{(-)}input)}{R_1}= _{(-)}input-V_{OUT}\$

\$_{(-)}input - \frac{R_2(V_{IN}-_{(-)}input)}{R_1} =V_{OUT}\$

```
(+)input into (-)input

remember: (+)input = V0*R1/(R1+R2)
remember: (-)input = (+)input
```

\$V_0\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} - \frac{R_2(V_{IN}-V_0\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2})}{R_1} =V_{OUT}\$

```
Tidy up:
```

\$V_0-V_{IN}\frac{R_2}{R_1}=V_{OUT}\$

[Verified here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Aa%20304%20320%20400%20320%200%2015%20-15%201000000%200.2501149931004139%200.24999999999999992%0Aw%20304%20304%20304%20256%200%0Ar%20240%20256%20304%20256%200%201000%0Ar%20304%20256%20400%20256%200%205000%0Ar%20304%20384%20304%20432%200%205000%0Ar%20240%20384%20304%20384%200%201000%0A172%20304%20432%20304%20464%200%206%201.5%205%200%200%200.5%20Voltage%0Aw%20304%20384%20304%20336%200%0Aw%20400%20256%20400%20320%200%0A368%20400%20320%20464%20320%200%200%0Ag%20240%20384%20224%20384%200%0A172%20240%20256%20192%20256%200%206%202.6%205%200%200%200.5%20Voltage%0Ax%20135%20213%20496%20216%204%2024%201.5%5Csminus%5Cs2.6%5Cstimes%5Cs5%5Csis%5Cs-11.5%0A)

Comment: Instead of using voltage dividing at the +input I could've used kirchoffs current law (which I did use for the -input). But I used both to help as much as possible. Good Luck in your adventure of learning electronics :) And if you think my answer is correct, mark it as your answer.